# OLingo OData2 Security

Tags: security, authorization, odata, olingo

I am just done with a basic POC of Olingo(OData), now I want to make the client calls secured and authorized.

So, Can anybody tell me how to make a odata request secure using OLingo?

Comment: Isn't it a REST API? You just need to make the URL `https` to make it secure.

Comment: Thanks Neil. It's a rest API but how it provides me username/password authentication.

Comment: Don't you specify the server URL somewhere? Maybe it's under the covers but there must be an URL.

Comment: @Manuj: are you writing a `ODataProducer`  or a `ODataConsumer` using olingo? and which version of OData are you using 2 or 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard Java EE Basic or Digest Authentication by adding a 'Security Constraint' element to your web.xml.

check the following link for a tutorial how to do this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html